# Running collapse command in Stata without losing key variables?

Tags: stata

How can I run the following consecutive `collapse` commands in Stata without losing all of my variables?

For example, when I run:

```
collapse (first) Complete num_countries, by(year Region name)
collapse (sum) Complete (first) num_countries, by(year Region)
```

I lose a variable called `all_m`, which I need for the following command:

```
collapse (first) all_m num_countries, by(year Region name)
collapse (sum) all_m (first) num_countries, by(year Region)
```

I tried storing it in a `local`, but the `collapse` command wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the structure of your data, it is hard to say but it sounds to me like you wouldn't even need to issue both sets of `collapse` commands since your data will be `collapse`d by the same variables each time and you are calculating the same statistics for `Complete` and `all_m`. This can be done like so:

```
collapse (first) Complete all_m num_countries, by(year Region name)
collapse (sum) Complete all_m (first) num_countries, by(year Region)
```

If I'm wrong, then simply do as @Nick Cox suggested or use `preserve` and `restore`.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want two different `collapse`d versions of the same dataset. Just read in the original data again before the second `collapse`.

It's not clear what you tried, but it sounds doomed: at most a local macro could be used to hold a variable name, but if the variable itself is removed, that benefits you nothing.